# No me devuelve el valor de AJAX

Tags: java, java-ee

Tengo un index en la ruta webcontent/index.jsp y este llama a un servlet a traves de ajax y me devuelve el valor

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post('actionServlet', {
    valor: "1"


  },function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText)
    $('#resultado').html(responseText);
 });
})
```

luego tengo otro jsp en webcontent/jsp/productos.jsp y tiene ese mismo script pero dentro de una funcion click

```
 $('#enviar').click(function() {
    var producto = $('#Fproducto').val();
    var unidades = $('#Funidades').val();
    alert("Hola");

    $.post('actionServlet', {
        valor: "1"
    },function(responseText) {
        alert(responseText)
        $('#resultado').html(responseText);
    });


});
```

pues en este momento al pulsar el botón no me devuelve nada.Solo el alert("Hola") y no el ok que devuelve el otro.

Este es el servlet, uso el mismo para los dos JSP

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse         response) throws IOException {

    response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String valorServlet = request.getParameter("valorServlet");
    out.println("OK");


}
```

He intentado de todo pero no encuentro el problemas.¿Algún solución?, muchas gracias

Comment: Intenta sacar la respuesta así: `response.getWriter().write("Ok");` En cuanto a esta línea: `String valorServlet = request.getParameter("valorServlet");`, debes comentarla temporalmente, porque realmente no estás enviando ningún valor con la clave `valorServlet`. No sé si eso te levante un error o una excepción... Verifica que el nombre del Servelet sea correcto.

Comment: pero si me diera un exception me lo daría también en el index no?

Comment: No sé realmente. Yo nunca he usado Servlets. De todos modos ¿probaste comentando esa línea por si acaso? Debes eliminar cualquier riesgo de error cuando pruebas código, haciendo las cosas lo más simple posibles.  Y, dado que aquí `$.post('actionServlet', {` estás mandando a `actionServlet`, ¿realmente el Servlet se llama así? Yo tengo experiencia con Ajax en entornos PHP y una de las cosas que hay que asegurar es que la petición se está enviando al lugar correcto.

Comment: Lo que sucede, es que tienes los jsp´s en diferentes rutas, de tal manera que estas poniendo la ruta relativa, a ver trata de ponerle así: **'../actionServlet'**

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es de URL, en la pagina index.jsp es diferente a la de productos.jsp y en la peticion POST se hace a ese servlet pero seria jsp/actionServlet.

Puedes salir facilmente de dudas con el debug del navegador y verificar a que URL esta haciendo la petición

Comment: pero el servlet es el mismo que usa el index, lo que cambia es que el jsp productos esta en una carpeta

Comment: pero el jsp esta dentro de una carpeta, ¿no te cambia la url en productos.jsp? `$.post('jsp/actionServlet', {
        valor: "1"
    },function(responseText) {
        alert(responseText)
        $('#resultado').html(responseText);
    });`